# Powershell validate textbox for dates

Tags: powershell, validation, user-interface

I'm trying to validate a textbox in Powershell. It should only allow the format dd.MM.yyyy (f.e 22.11.2022). Yet if I type some random characters (f.e 20.2), I get erros instead of a MessageBox.

I've tried something like this:

```
if($Starttextbox.Text -as [DateTime] -or $Endtextbox.Text -as [DateTime]){
  "do something"
}else{
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Type in correct format','format','Ok','Error')
}
```

Comment: Use a date picker control instead of a textbox. Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: The point of this task is not to use a date picker, but a textbox.

Comment: $abc = new-object -TypeName datetime  if([datetime]::TryParse($Starttextbox.Text, [ref][datetime]$abc) or [datetime]::TryParse($Endtextbox.Text, [ref][datetime]$abc))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the regex for dates in the format of dd.mm.yyyy:

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a small function and use a combination of RegEx and Get-Date commandlet, like below.

```
$StartDate = '22.12.2022' #Good
$EndDate = '22.19.2022' #Bad

function Get-ValidDate { param($DateToCheck)
    $DateToCheck -match '(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})' | Out-Null
    if($matches.count -eq 4) {
        $ValidDate = $(Get-Date -Date "$($matches[2])-$($matches[1])-$($matches[3])" -Format 'dd.MM.yyyy') 2>> $NULL
    }
    if($DateToCheck -eq $ValidDate) {
        return "GoodDate"
    }
}

if((Get-ValidDate $StartDate) -and (Get-ValidDate $EndDate)) {
    Write-Host "These are Good Dates!" # DO STUFF
} else {
    Write-Host "These are Bad Dates!" # MESSAGEBOX
}
```

2>>$NULL  will remove your Get-Date error messages as all you're looking for is a valid datetime from Get-Date. Function will only return on RegEx match and a valid date.